# The property of being a $\lambda$-complete ultrafilter is $\Pi_1$.

Tags: set-theory, filters

I am trying to show that being a $\lambda$-complete ultrafilter is a $\Pi_1$ statement. Right now I have that $U$ is $\lambda$-complete iff $\forall \beta<\lambda\left( \langle U_{\alpha}:\alpha<\beta\rangle\in U^{\beta}\implies \bigcap_{\alpha<\beta} U_{\alpha}\in U\right).$ I'll call that statement $\varphi$. so far no unbounded quantifiers

Power sets are $\Pi_1$, and so it is the set $U^{\beta}$ which is giving problems (as it's a function space just like $2^X$ is). Note the subtle difference that the statement "$Y=2^X$" is $\Pi_1$ but $"Y\in 2^X"$ is $\Delta_0$. So actually I have to pay attention to exactly what is happening to $U^{\beta}$ in $\varphi$. I have "$\langle U_{\alpha}:\alpha<\beta\rangle\in U^{\beta}$", not that something *equals* $U^{\beta}$. So isn't that whole thing to the left of the $\implies$ actually $\Delta_0$? Is someone able to point out *exactly* where this $\forall$ quantifier comes in here?

Comment: You should probably say that "for every sequence" something happens. What you have written is that some specific sequence has some property.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you! I'm not wanting to write a separate question for it, if that's okay, but does this exact same argument hold for an ultrafilter being normal? The diagonal intersection doesn't add anything new, yes?

Comment: Yes, the argument is very similar. It may be useful as well to think about $\Pi_1,\Sigma_1$, etc., in terms of models. A $\Pi_1$ property is one that is preserved downwards (from a model of  enough set theory to any of its submodels), a $\Sigma_1$ property is one preserved upwards, and $\Delta_1$ properties are absolute between models and submodels. This is a characterization you may want to look into, because it is very useful in practice: rather than thinking about properties in terms of their syntax, I find it easier to think of their behavior when passing to inner or outer models.

Comment: See I figured this, but didn't know how this is useful in practice. For example, how do we know $\kappa$-completeness reflects downwards without knowing it's $\Pi_1$?

Comment: Say that $U$ is a $\lambda$-complete ultrafilter, and $M$ is an inner model with $U\in M$. Since $U$ contains the intersection of all $<\lambda$-sequences of its members, in particular, it contains the intersection of all those sequences that belong to $M$, so it is $\lambda$-complete in $M$. That's it. On the other hand, it may well be that $M$ misses many $<\lambda$-sequences, so from the fact that $U$ is $\lambda$-complete in $M$, we should not expect to be able to conclude that it is also $\lambda$-complete in $V$ (and indeed, this is not always the case).

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense. Does this prove it's $\Pi_1$? Couldn't it be just about anything else, though? If $\varphi$ is $\Pi_1$, then it reflects downwards, but that is not an iff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement tacitly has a universal quantifier over the sequence $\langle U_\alpha\rangle$, since you want the implication to hold for *all* $\langle U_\alpha\rangle\in U^\beta$.  For any fixed set $x$, you can assert that $x\in U^\beta$ using only bounded quantifiers.  However, here you are quantifying over *all* elements $x\in U^\beta$, and that requires an unbounded quantifier since you cannot define the set $U^\beta$ using only bounded quantifiers.

That is, you can write down a $\Delta_0$ formula $\psi(x,\beta,U)$ which says that $x\in U^\beta$.  However, your formula $\varphi$ has the form $\forall \beta<\lambda\ \forall x (\psi(x,\beta,U)\rightarrow \dots)$ and the unbounded quantifier on $x$ makes this $\Pi_1$.

Comment: How is this quantifier unbounded? Aren't I only quantifying over members of some particular set (namely $U^{\beta}$?

Comment: But you can't just write down specific sets in the language of set theory; you can only use variables.  The symbol "$U^\beta$" is not part of the language of set theory.

Comment: You could introduce a variable $y$ to represent $U^\beta$, but then you would have to both quantify over $y$ (since the only free variables in your overall formula should be $U$ and $\lambda$) and express that $y$ is equal to $U^\beta$ as part of your formula.  Both of these things would require unbounded quantifiers.

Comment: Perfect clarification. Thank you so much for your help!